# Get second Row from the given result set using spring data jpa query

Tags: spring-data-jpa, querydsl, jparepository

I have a spring-data-jpa repository.

```
interface SomeRepository : JpaRepository<SomeEntity, String> {
fun findFirstBySomeColOrderByCreatedAtDesc(someCol: String): SomeEntity
}
```

So this gives me the top row from the result set.

I want to write another query that gives me the second row if it exists and null otherwise i.e. if there is only one row? Is that feasible to write that kind of query using similar to what I have to get the First row.
I tried with

```
fun findSecondBySomeColOrderByCreatedAtDesc(someCol: String): SomeEntity
```

it returns top two rows.